# Set class based on asynchronous object

Tags: angular

How do you use get the value of breakpointObserver to return a true/false value based on device orientation if it is asynchronous? At the moment, it always results false and I can't map the correct stylesheet.

Code below:

**View**

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let feature of features">
    <div [ngClass]="setFeatureCardColumnWidth(isMobile)" aos-animate data-aos="fade-up">
      <app-home-feature-card title="{{ feature.title }}" description="{{ feature.description }}"
        image="{{ feature.image }}">
      </app-home-feature-card>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

**Controller**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset]);
  }

  setFeatureCardColumnWidth(isMobile) {
    if (!isMobile) {
      return 'col-lg-4';
    } else {
      return 'col-md-12';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BreakpointObserver.observe` returns an Observable as many of the answerers already stated. But you do not need to subscribe and unsubscribe manually. Make use of the async pipe and map your stream before to your required values.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.columnWidth$ = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset]).pipe(
    map(isHandset => isHandset ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-lg-4')
  );
}
```

And in your template you can for example use

```html
<div [ngClass]="columnWidth$ | async"></div>
```

You also do not need an `isMobile` property and do the checks in your component. Instead modify the Observable stream.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to use observables in Angular templates. Change `isMobile` to `(isMobile | async)`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use `Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait` instead of `Breakpoints.Handset`, because the last observes both Portrait and Lancscape, so it would always match.

Secondly, you need to subscribe to the observable (so you will know when the orientation changes) and check if the result matches (so you will know if the new orientation is portrait or not):

```js
this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait]).subscribe(
  result => {
    this.isMobile = result.matches;
  }
);
```

And you don't need to pass `isMobile` to your function, you can write it like this:

```js
getFeatureCardColumnWidth() {
if (!this.isMobile) {
  return 'col-lg-4';
} else {
  return 'col-md-12';
}
```

Full code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fxcok-observe-handset-portrait

---

### Update

If you wish to make less changes to your code:

1. Change `Breakpoints.Handset` to `Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait` as follows:

```js
this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait]);
```

2. In your template use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), and pass the `matches` attribute to your function as follows:

```js
setFeatureCardColumnWidth((isMobile | async)?.matches)
```